# Comparison of Drop , Delete or Truncate in MySQL on basis of query running speed

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

Which query is faster among these:

1. DROP TABLE table_Name
2. TRUNCATE TABLE table_Name
3. DELETE FROM table_Name

Comment: Wouldnt it be quicker to test this for yourself?

Comment: Probably `truncate`, but you would need to test it yourself.

Comment: Does it matter? They do different things.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-delete-drop-and-truncate/?ref=rp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, for a table with a significant number of rows, I would suppose that `drop` is the fastest operation, then `truncate`, and finally `delete`.

Rationale:

- `drop` and `truncate` are DDL operations, as opposed to `delete`, which is a DML operation; as the number of rows increases, the performance of `delete` degrades quickly (while DDL operations are less dependent on the underlying dataset size).
- in MySQL, `truncate` under the hood `drop`s and recreates the table - so it cannot be faster than a straight `drop`